# How do I get the pixel locations of text and other elements in a UWP ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a `ListView` in my UWP app with an `ItemTemplate` that consists of a `Path` geometry and a `TextBox`:

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="ListView"
    CanDragItems="True"
    CanReorderItems="True"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Categories}">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="myData:Category">
            <StackPanel
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                ToolTipService.ToolTip="{x:Bind CategoryString, Mode=OneWay}">

                <Path                                        
                    Margin="14, 10, 4, 0"
                    Width="10"
                    Height="10"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Data="{x:Bind SymbolGeometry, Mode=OneWay}"
                    Fill="{x:Bind Colour, Mode=OneWay}"/>

                <TextBox 
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    Text="{x:Bind LegendLabel, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

As part of exporting a piece of the UI to an SVG I would like to find the locations (in pixel coordinates relative to any parent item) of the `TextBox` text and `Path` geometry for each item in the `ListView`. Does anybody know how to achieve this? As the `ListView` items are dependant on user input I'm unsure how to retrieve the necessary information.

I'm aware UIElements can be converted to bitmaps for export, however this does not fulfil the requirements of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [UIElement.TransformToVisual(UIElement) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.transformtovisual?view=winrt-19041) and [GeneralTransform.TransformPoint(Point) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.generaltransform.transformpoint?view=winrt-19041) to get the locations of UIElement objects.

Please check the following code:

```
for(int i=0;i<ListView.Items.Count;i++)
{
    var item = ListView.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ListViewItem;

    var path = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(item.ContentTemplateRoot as DependencyObject, 0) as Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Path;
    var box = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(item.ContentTemplateRoot as DependencyObject, 1) as TextBox;
    var visual1 = path.TransformToVisual(ListView); //Select the ListView control as the parent element.
    var point = visual1.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));

    var visual2 = box.TransformToVisual(ListView);
    var point2 = visual2.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));

}
```